# AJAX data in template of Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am populating [Select2](https://select2.org) with AJAX data. My code is like below.

```
    function formatState(state) {
        if (!state.id) { return state.text; }
        var output = $('<span></span>');   // I would like get data `text[1]` of `processResults` here.
        return output;
    };

    //more code here

    cellEle.html(`<select multiple="multiple"></select>`);
    
    let selectEle = cellEle.children("select").select2({

        //more code here
        
        ajax: {

            //more code here

            processResults: function (data) {                
                var options = [];
                if (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, text) {
                        options.push({ id: index, text: text[0]});
                    });
                }
                return {
                    results: options,
                    more: false
                };
            },
        },
        templateSelection: formatState,
    });
```

I would like get AJAX data `text[1]` of `processResults` inside `formatState()` of `templateSelection`.

How can I get it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass any extra data via `processResults`. In your case it can be

```js
var options = [];
if (data) {
  $.each(data.items, function (index, text) {
    options.push({ id: index, text: text[0], text2: text[1] /* <-- extra data */});
  });
}
return {
  results: options,
  more: false
};
```

Then access it in `templateSelection`

```js
if (!state.id) {
  return state.text;
}
return $(`<span>${state.text} & ${state.text2}</span>`);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/moshfeu/3hrupdn1/22/

Comment: Thanks @Mosh Feu. Could you please help me in this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71043039/tooltip-is-not-closing-with-select2